# Given two vectors $A$, $B$, if the angle $\theta$ between them is such that $\cos \theta = 1$, then A, B have the same direction

Tags: linear-algebra

Exercise no.10 from the fourth section of the first chapter of Serge Lang's book on Linear Algebra asks to prove the following:

Given $A$, $B$ two non-zero vectors in the $n$-space, with $\theta$ the angle between them such that $\cos \theta = 1$, prove that $A$ and $B$ have the same direction.

Instead, if $\cos \theta = -1$, prove that they have opposite direction.

For $A$ and $B$ to have the same direction, there has to be a number $c \gt 0$ such that $cA = B$. Instead, for them to have th opposite direction there has to be a number $d \lt 0$ such that $dA = B$.

Since $\cos \theta = 1$ and I know that:
$$\cos \theta = \frac{A \cdot B}{\Vert A \Vert \Vert B \Vert}$$
it follows that :
$$\frac{A \cdot B}{\Vert A \Vert \Vert B \Vert} = 1$$
$$A \cdot B = \Vert A \Vert \Vert B \Vert$$
And I'm stuck here, it looks like there are some easy algebraic passages to go further and actually find a way to express $B$ as $cA$ but I cannot find them.

I guess one thing I could do is squaring both members and take advantage of the few theorems I already proved in this first chapter.

Also the second part with $\cos \theta = -1$ will definitely follow from the first part of the proof, just by changing signs.

I would really appreciate some advices on how to continue the proof(or if it is the case how to properly begin it anew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle $\theta$ between two non-zero vectors clearly satisfies that $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

So, $\cos \theta = 1$ implies that $\theta = 0$ and $\cos \theta = -1$ that $\theta = \pi$.

Comment: Oh I see, it was definitely easier to find the angle between the two vectors than to do what I was trying to. I think this answer will do, thank you!